# VideoWriter with 4k images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

Is there any way to use 4k images to make 4k mp4 video with the VideoWriter function? I used 38 4k images to write a 4k video. But I got the error :Frame must be between 64x64 and 1088x1920.     clear all

```
load images.mat% size of images is 2160x3840x3x38
myVideo = VideoWriter('A9_B4_4k.mp4','MPEG-4');
myVideo.FrameRate = 30;
myVideo.Quality = 100;
open(myVideo);
    writeVideo(myVideo,images);
close(myVideo);
```

Comment: Have you tried a different encoder?

Comment: I tried with motion jpeg. It did work. But wether is it possible to make mp4 video with mpeg-4 encoder?

Comment: A couple questions... 1) What version of MATLAB are you running? 2) Could you post the full error message displayed, or at least the error message identifier (you can get it from, for example, [`lasterror`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lasterror.html) after you generate the above error)?

Comment: 1) I use the MATLAB R2015a

Comment: 2) the error is 'Frame must be between 64x64 and 1088x1920 ' .